# Efficient way to concatenate a list of lists into a single pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently building a pandas data frame from a list of lists using the following approach:

```
a = [{"this":4,"that":[5,4,5,6]},
    {"this":6,"that":[3,5,6,8,3,25]}]
out = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in a])
```

Is this fairly computationally intensive? Is there a more efficient way to carry out this procedure? Basically, I need to convert about 500K lists like this into a single flat data frame that has the form:

```
out["this"]
[1]: [4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6]
out["that"]
[2]: [5,4,5,6,3,5,6,8,3,25]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want the resulting DataFrame to look like?

Comment: thanks for the question... I updated my original question to include that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to anything. Just read it as a dataframe.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = [{"this":4,"that":5}, {"this":6,"that":7}]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a)
>>> print(df)
    that  this
0     5     4
1     7     6
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... I should have included an exception in my original question... I edited my original question to demonstrate the added complexity, which is why I arrived at the solution I did. Thanks again.